# I want to retrieve the json_decode data. How to write foreach here

Tags: php

```
$classconducted = json_encode(array('segment'=>$segment,'Board'=>$board,'classFiveSubject'=>$subject5,'classeightboard'=>$eightboard,'classeightsubject'=>$subject8,'classTenthboard'=>$tenthboard,'classTenthsubject'=>$subject8,'engineering'=>$engineering));
```

$in = '{"segment":["Class I-V Tuition","Class VI-VIII Tuition","Class IX-X Tuition"],"Board":["cbse","cse/Ise","State"],"classFiveSubject":["allsubject","science"],"classeightboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classeightsubject":null,"classTenthboard":["cbse","cse/Ise"],"classTenthsubject":null,"engineering":null}';
        print_r( json_decode($in) );

myoutput:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [segment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Class I-V Tuition
            [1] => Class VI-VIII Tuition
            [2] => Class IX-X Tuition
        )

    [Board] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
            [2] => State
        )

    [classFiveSubject] => Array
        (
            [0] => allsubject
            [1] => science
        )

    [classeightboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
        )

    [classeightsubject] =>
    [classTenthboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
            [1] => cse/Ise
        )

    [classTenthsubject] =>
    [engineering] =>
)

I have used the following code to retrieve the data. but I could not workout it.can any one guide me how to solve this?
       <?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from tinfo");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$in=$row['classconducted'];
}
echo "<pre>";
$value=json_decode($in, true);//echo count($in); exit;
foreach ($value as $k => $val)    
{
echo "$k | $val <br />";
} 
?>
```

The output is:Here it is listing the indexing key and the value is not coming how to user the foreach here.I want to retrieve the key and value.

```
segment | Array 
Board | Array 
classFiveSubject | Array 
classeightboard | Array 
classeightsubject | Array 
classTenthboard |  
classTenthsubject | Array 
engineering | Array 

I want the  output form my json_decode  like this:
segment:Class I-V Tuition
Board:CBSE,STATE
classFiveSubject:AllSubject,Maths,Science
segment:Class VI-VIII Tuition
Board:CBSE, STATE
classEightSUbject:AllSubject,Maths,Science
```

can anyone give me the propercode? what are the ways to list the json_decode data.

Comment: $arr = json_decode( $in, TRUE );
foreach ( $arr as $key => $data ){
/* $data is an array? */
}

Comment: I have done .after that it shows like that.can you please trigger out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but try:

```html
foreach (json_decode($in, true) as $key => $val) {

  echo $key.': ';
  if (is_array($val))
    echo implode(',', $val) . "\n";
  else
    echo $val . "\n";
  
}
```

Comment: It's great.My sincere thanks to you .I will make very simple. $classconducted = json_encode(array('segment'=>$segment,'Board'=>$board,'classFiveSubject'=>$subject5,'classeightboard'=>$eightboard,'classeightsubject'=>$subject8,'classTenthboard'=>$tenthboard,'classTenthsubject'=>$subject8,'engineering'=>'')); enginnering index doesnot contain any values how to avoid the null values it is showing empty key with no values those which doesn't contain any values. I updated the question also

Answer (score 0):

```
define('BR', '<br />');

$json = json_decode($in, true);

foreach ($json as $key => $arr ) {
    echo $key.BR;

    foreach( $arr as $value ) {
        echo $value.BR; 
    }

}
```